# linqpad ; expected

Tags: linqpad

I'm trying to run the following as a "C# expression"

```
Directory.GetDirectoryRoot( @"C:\Users\DMORIN\Documents\Penguino\Shelves\session").Dump();
```

I get the error "; expected"

If I copy and paste that into an existing example query (replacing the example) it works.

eg.  If I replace the contents of "Readme.First()" with the code above, things work.  If I make a new query with language "C# statements" I get the error.

Comment: Drop the `;` at the end.

Comment: What version of linqpad are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**F4** and check your **Additional Namespace Imports**.

You can get the error if, for example, you have a space in there eg System Windows Forms instead of System.Windows.Forms.

And you will need to save it back as the default for new queries if there is a problem.

Comment: That was it.  I had some mistakes in the namespace imports.  I just took one of the sample, did F4, and then did "Set as default for new queries" to clean that up.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `C# expression`, LinqPad expects an expression, not a statement.

You need to remove the `;` at the end of the line.

Comment: I still get the problem when I put:

Directory.GetDirectoryRoot( @"C:\Users\DMORIN\Documents\Penguino\Shelves\session").Dump()

as a "c# expression" in a new query.

It still works if I paste over an existing sample.

Comment: @Derek - Weird. Restart linqpad.

Comment: I've restarted many times.  It works if I open "Readme.First()" and then do "New Query, same properties".  But if I just do "New Query" I get the error.  To be consistent, let's say I am using the following:

Directory.GetDirectoryRoot( @"C:\Users\DMORIN\Documents\Penguino\Shelves\session").Dump();

as "C# Statement(s)"

Comment: @Derek - I am getting `C:\\` as result. No errors. Using version 4.43.06.

Comment: I'm on the same version... still a mystery